# Curl error 10054 (56) on a domain I can otherwise connect to

Tags: php, curl, openssl

I'm using just a standard curl request to get to the domain `www.fredmeyer.com`.

I am completely unable to connect here and the request fails after about 4 seconds.

The code I'm using:

```
public function __construct($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, K::UserAgent());
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $this->curl = $curl;
}
```

then just running `curl_exec` on the curl object. Using `curl_errno` function I get error 56 back.

I'm able to access this site in the browser with no problems on the same machine, so I'm not sure why curl isn't working.

Using `openssl` directly I can establish a connection:

```
user@n060db551lnazxp2:~/t# openssl s_client -connect www.fredmeyer.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5714 bytes and written 302 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 3C46D235C3E5A627AF8BB0849BFE380E287C65EF6D018E11D437EDC65B59648B
    Session-ID-ctx:
```

I've tried messing around with curl's SSL cipher without any luck.

Comment: add `curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );` to your curl option.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder - Very bad advice; see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Comment: @jww for debugging purpose, and turn it back on once the problem is fixed.

Comment: @sk099 - I think cURL on Windows can use Microsoft's S-Channel. Please state what cURL is using for its underlying security library. Also state your version of Windows.

Comment: i'm not even using windows, i'm using ubuntu with openssl version 1.1.0f via php/curl. actually, i've tried this on both windows and an ubuntu server (different host as well) so there isn't any blocking going on. the verifyhost thing didn't work either